# NPE when adding inflated button

Tags: android, android-layout

I try to create new Button programatically and it to existing ViewGroup (I moved from custom to classical LinearLayout to ensure bug is not in custom ViewGroup).

A code is simple and it is working in different use case:

```
private void appendTile() {
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.template_tile, null);
    view.setId(View.generateViewId());
    view.setOnClickListener(tileListener);
    hiddenPicture.addView(view, view.getLayoutParams());
}
```

template_tile.xml:

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text=""
style="@style/FormulaValue" />
```

But it fails, because `view.getLayoutParams()` is `null` (though there are `layout_width` and `layout_height` in the XML).

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.width' on a null object reference
   at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:6453)
   at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:6735)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(LinearLayout.java:1901)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1799)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:62)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3945)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3786)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3758)
   at lelisoft.com.lelimath.activities.PuzzleActivity.appendTile(PuzzleActivity.java:39)
   at lelisoft.com.lelimath.activities.PuzzleActivity.onCreate(PuzzleActivity.java:31)
```

I went to ViewGroups constructor and it reads width from null params. What shall I do differently in my activity? Why `layout_width` from XML is not set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LayoutParams` are specific to the container (i.e. the `ViewGroup`). Since you are inflating without a `root` parameter, the [layout parameters are ignored](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/LayoutInflater.java#L496), because there is simply no "proper" way to create a suitable instance of `LayoutParams` without knowing the container type.

To use the layout parameters from XML, you need to supply a root `ViewGroup` when inflating:

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
    R.layout.template_tile,
    hiddenPicture,
    false // don't attachToRoot
);
view.setId(View.generateViewId());
view.setOnClickListener(tileListener);
hiddenPicture.addView(view, view.getLayoutParams());
```

Note that the third parameter `attachToRoot` is `false` here. If you set it to `true`, the inflated view is automatically attached to its parent container, which simplifies the typical case.

However, when `attachToRoot == true` the return value from `inflate()` is not the `Button` instance but `hiddenPicture`, i.e. the supplied root `View` of the affected hierarchy.

In that case, never get direct access to the `Button` object. Since you do manual setup (attach a listener, set the ID) on the inflated button, manual attach is simpler.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I am happy that I know more details now.

Answer (score 2):

Layout params come from the parent object. Since you're inflating with a null parent, your view doesn't have layout params yet.

Replace

```
addView(view, view.getLayoutParams())
```

with

```
addView(view)
```

to not supply the layout params yourself and let the framework generate ones for you.

Comment: I might be wrong, but doesn't this simply ignore any layout parameters from the XML and generate default `LayoutParams` for the container?

Comment: Yes, all of the layout_* attributes have no effect. I don't know what OP expects but this is one way to get rid of the NPE. Inflating with a parent as in your answer is another. Though adding the view manually doesn't really add value; could as well let the inflation step do the adding.

Comment: `inflate()` returns the supplied root view and not the `Button` when `attachToRoot=true`. If you need to do any "adjustments" (like attaching a listener) to the inflated `Button`, the manual attach is actually the simpler way.

Comment: I tried View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.template_tile, hiddenPicture); but the button did not show.

Comment: OP expects that layout width and height will be set as defined from XML and there will be no NPE.